# Error message when attempting to stop Parity in Ubuntu

Tags: parity

I attempted to stop parity and am getting an error message:

> Failed to stop io.parity.ethereum.service: Unit
>   io.parity.ethereum.service not loaded.

Any suggestion for why this occurred? This is what I did: Once logged in as the sudo user in Ubuntu, from my home directory, I entered:

```
sudo systemctl stop io.parity.ethereum
```

The error msg followed.
Here is Parity version and install info in case it helps:

> Version:
>   Parity/v1.5.0-beta-d2e6fc0-20170119/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.14.0

Also, in case it matters: I installed Parity with the bash command

`curl https://get.parity.io -Lk`

on Ubuntu.
TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install script does not create and run a service as far as I know. You would have to run Parity manually on Ubuntu. However, if you are certain you have a parity service, you can check the status with:

```
systemctl status io.parity.ethereum
```

If this does not work, you can check for a running node with:

```
ps aux | grep -i parity
```

If it shows you can try to stop it cleanly with:

```
killall -HUP parity
```

And now, please update your node (using the same bash script) to 1.6.3, your version is very old.